# How to custom left/right align items in android jetpack compose Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, material-components-android

I want a Row in Jetpack Compose, something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| A |   B   |                                  | C |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I want A & B to be left aligned, next to each other and C at the end. I don't know if the existing horizontal arrangement has ways to do this. Also I think, nesting Rows may not be a good idea. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use `Spacer` with [`Modifier.weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)):

```
Row {
    Text("a")
    Text("b")
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    Text("c")
}
```

In more complex scenario, when your first text is multiline, you can apply `Modifier.weight` to this item itself - and making sure content inside is aligned as you expect, e.g. `Start` in this case by default:

```
Row {
    Text(
        "some\nmultiline\ntext",
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
    )
    Text("c")
}
```

Comment: it will not work for long text in the case of the first text

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer will not work if the first Text is too long. In that case,  the third text will not be shown.

This should work:

```
                Row {
                    Text("a")
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        text = "b"
                    )
                    Text("c")
                }
```